# Is it possible to use a slider rather than a static clickable feature to adjust the transparency of layers in apps built with Experience Builder?

Tags: layers, transparency-opacity, web, arcgis-experience-builder

I have built an app for a client that allows the user to adjust the transparency of all layers in it on their end.  The interface looks like this:

[image]

The client, who is used to using apps that I have previously built for them in the old Web AppBuilder format, dislikes this interface and wants ability to adjust the transparency to be a slider, like shown here in an old AppBuilder app:

[image]

My question is: Has anyone found a way to implement this functionality in Experience Builder?